# В какой части возникает ошибка

Tags: python

Все время выдает `string index out of range`, но я не вижу в чем проблема. Вот моя функция, она должна фильтровать `leest` так, чтобы в конце были только буквы, от а до я.

```
        leest2 = copy.copy(leest)
        iterator = 0
        for i in leest:
            if ord(i[-1]) in range(ord('А'), ord('Я')) or ord(i[-1]) in range(ord('а'), ord('я')):
                pass
            else:
                leest2[iterator] = i[0: -1]
            iterator += 1
        return leest2
```

Заодно может и способ получше посоветуете? Заранее спасибо за помощь!
P.S. В `leest` только слова от 2их символов

`leest =  ['Когда', 'Маргарита', 'дошла', 'до', 'последних', 'слов', 'главы', 'Так', 'встретил', 'рассвет', 'пятнадцатого', 'нисана', 'пятый', 'прокуратор', 'Иудеи', 'Понтий', 'Пилат»']`

Comment: Нужна трасса ошибки, в ней указано в каком месте возникла ошибка

Comment: ```if ord(i[-1]) in range(ord('А'), ord('Я')) or ord(i[-1]) in range(ord('а'), ord('я')):
IndexError: string index out of range``` 
Вот тут

Comment: Приводите `i[-1]` к одному регистру, тогда будет только одна проверка -- на один регистр, например на верхний. Непонятно чем `leest` заполнен, но если на пустой список вызвать `[-1]` будет такая же ошибка (`[][-1]`). Поэтому, возможно вам нужно проверять что `i` не пустой

Comment: ```i``` никогда не пустой, я написал в вопросе

Comment: Ок, предоставьте в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), а конкретно нужен пример `leest`, чтобы любой мог взять ваш код, запустить и получить вашу ошибку. А гадать, что у вас не так лишь время терять

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
def fun(s):
    return ''.join(x for x in s 
                   if ord('а') <= ord(x.casefold()) <= ord('я') 
                   or ord(x.casefold()) == ord('ё'))
```

PS  код буквы `ё` больше кода буквы `я`, поэтому для `ё` нужна отдельная проверка:

```
print(ord('ё') < ord('а'))
# False
```

Проверка:

```
In [167]: fun('A simple Example! Вот простой ПримЁр.')
Out[167]: 'ВотпростойПримЁр'
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку, ord ожидает символ, но вместо него строка с длиной
А о том что 'ё' больше 'я' не знал, спасибо

Comment: @Krasivyi_User9123, можете привести пример строки для воспроизведения ошибки?